# If I travel from Vancouver, Canada to Los Angeles, USA and back, how many times will my passport be stamped and when?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lax, yvr

I normally fly from Bellingham International Airport, USA (BLI) because I want to keep my passport pages blank.

Comment: So, get a NEXUS card. Problem solved.

Comment: Why do you want to keep your passport pages blank?

Comment: I have at least forty US immigration stamps - atop of each other - on one page of the passport. Nobody ever cares. Why would you worry about the fill of stamps in your passport??

Comment: My passport is from canada

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to tell. Both the CBP and CBSA fully have the authority to stamp every time you cross the border inwards, neither country has exit checks but it's almost totally random.

*Theoretically* the CBP stamps once per validity so if you cross the US border then you get a stamp once and no more for the next three months if you have an ESTA or six if you move on a B1/B2 visa.

CBSA tends to stamp on every border crossing.

Or not.

Land crossings, especially in a car tends to have less stamps than air.

Or not.

This is a useful answer.

Or not.

Comment: This is the answer unless someone wants to interview all Officers in the two districts and get firm commitments from them on whether or not they stamp, then ask them for their upcoming work schedules, then plan you travel around that.  Am I being comically pedantic?  Yes, but this answer is still correct.

Comment: As a Canadian citizen, OP isn't eligible for ESTA.

Comment: Could be -- if you live in Vancouver, to get to BLI you need to cross on land which very well might result in fewer stamps.

Comment: @chx With a NEXUS card or (by land) enhanced driving licence, the "risk" of being stamped can be totally eradicated

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience (also a Canadian passport), US Homeland Security stamp in YVR (pre-clearance) and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Based purely on personal experience and 4 or 5 trips per year and taking into consideration my passport is from the US....

I never get stamped crossing by car in either direction.

I get stamped flying into Canada maybe 50% of the time.

I never get stamped flying into the US.

I would hazard a guess that if your record shows multiple crossings the less likely you are to be stamped. But ultimately it is up to the agent you deal with each time.

Answer (score 1):

You might be stamped at US preclearance at Vancouver, **that's it**. Even there, if you use an APC kiosk, the border agent may not stamp your passport, in which case you'd end up with zero stamps.